# Spring security: sporadic NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have simple web application with REST API and I want to secure it with token-based authentication.
Here is my security filter:

```
public class AuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

  public AuthFilter(RequestMatcher reqMatcher) {
    super(reqMatcher);
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    //30 line: here is first place in my code where exception occurred
    this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((req1, res1, auth) -> chain.doFilter(req1, res1)); 

    //32 line: second place in my code where exception occurred
    super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    String token = req.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);

    if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Token is not present!");
    }

    AuthToken authToken = new AuthToken(token);
    authToken.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(req));

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
  }
}
```

Authentication provider for user extraction by token:

```
@Component
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Autowired private UsersService usersService;
  @Autowired private TokensService tokensService;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    AuthToken authToken = (AuthToken) auth;

    String t = authToken.getToken();

    try {
      Token token = tokensService.get(t);

      if (token.isAdmin()) {
        User admin = User.createAdmin();

        return new AuthToken(t, admin);
      }

      User user = usersService.getBy(token);

      return new AuthToken(t, user);
    } catch (TokenNotFoundException e) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Token not found!");
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("User by token not found!");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
    return AuthToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth);
  }
}
```

And finally here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(filter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }

  protected AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter() throws Exception {
    AuthFilter filter = new AuthFilter(
      new RegexRequestMatcher("^(\\/rest)(?!(\\/settings)|(\\/security))(\\/?.*)", null));

    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());

    return filter;
  }
}
```

All works fine, but `NullPointerException` is raised periodically when I send requests to endpoints. Not every request ends up with exception, it can be after 10 or 20 requests, here is no order with this exception. Requests to the same endpoints can work well but after several requests `NullPointerException` is raised. Also, exception can be thrown with first request.

Here is stacktrace:

```
2018-04-20 11:14:33.162 ERROR 3868 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at ru.asu.edu.studyload.security.AuthFilter.lambda$0(AuthFilter.java:30) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:326) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at ru.asu.edu.studyload.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:32) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just experienced the same issue and noticed the problem is in calling

> this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((req1, res1, auth) -> chain.doFilter(req1, res1));

inside the `doFilter` method. `doFilter` is not thread safe and we are using the `chain` variable inside the a lambda function. When we have multiple concurrent requests accessing this filter we can hit a race condition.

```
[nio-8080-exec-6] => doFilter() with (chain 1285350683)
[nio-8080-exec-7] => doFilter() with (chain 1471502546)
[nio-8080-exec-6] => setAuthenticationSuccessHandler lambda (continue chain 1471502546)
[nio-8080-exec-7] => setAuthenticationSuccessHandler lambda (continue chain 1471502546)
[nio-8080-exec-7] => c.p.gbm.api.rest.RestEndpointsLogger : type=http method=GET endpoint=/test status-code=200
[nio-8080-exec-7] => setAuthenticationSuccessHandler lambda (release chain 1471502546)
2019-05-07 17:23:10.346 ERROR 68613 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in 
context with path [] threw exception 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

As we can see above, when thread 6 tries to run servlet.service() to resolve the request, thread 7 already released the chain setting the servlet to null.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how or why, but this filter implementation seems to work:

```
public class AuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

  public AuthFilter(RequestMatcher reqMatcher) {
    super(reqMatcher);

    this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((req1, res1, auth) -> { });
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    String token = req.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);

    if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Token is not present!");
    }

    AuthToken authToken = new AuthToken(token);
    authToken.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(req));

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest req, 
    HttpServletResponse res, 
    FilterChain chain, 
    Authentication auth
  ) throws IOException, ServletException {

    super.successfulAuthentication(req, res, chain, auth);

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
}
```